# Is Creative Commons a recoginsed license?

Tags: packaging, license

I would like to package an application that uses Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0:
http://www.gmaptool.eu/en/content/license

http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode

Is this a recognized Open Source license?
So can I package the code?

Thanks and kind regards,

Comment: Yes just like the GPL, BSD and MIT Licenses or you can just make your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creative Commons licenses are considered Open Source, yes.

However, the Creative Commons licenses are meant to be used for content (artwork, books, videos, music, etc…) and not really suitable for source code. Also, I do not see any source code available on that site. The Linux version download on that site is a zip file which only contains a pre-compiled binary, a text file which states the work is licensed under the CC-By-SA license, the readme.txt, and a copy of the LGPL v2.1 license.

It's quite unclear what the author? intends there. You should contact the author and ask for clarification, and for the author to publish the source code.